# SQL select query too slow on webhost, fine on localhost

Tags: sql, performance, select, memory

```
SELECT c.customers_lastname, 
cg.customers_group_name, 
dctc.coupons_id AS coupId, 
dcto.coupons_id AS coupIdUsed, 
dc.coupons_date_start AS coupStart, 
count(DISTINCT o.orders_id) AS totalorders, 
sum(op.products_quantity * op.final_price) AS ordersum 
from
customers c LEFT JOIN customers_groups cg ON cg.customers_group_id = c.customers_group_id 
LEFT JOIN (discount_coupons_to_customers dctc 
    LEFT JOIN discount_coupons dc ON dc.coupons_id = dctc.coupons_id 
    LEFT JOIN discount_coupons_to_orders dcto ON dcto.coupons_id = dctc.coupons_id 
) ON c.customers_id = dctc.customers_id, orders_products op, orders o 
WHERE c.customers_id = o.customers_id 
AND c.customers_promotions = '0' 
AND o.orders_id = op.orders_id 
GROUP BY c.customers_id
ORDER BY ordersum DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The above query returns all customers that ever bought anything in our webshop (and some extra data), sorted by total order amount. It runs fine on localhost (a few seconds) but takes up to a minute on remote server. To make matters worse, the query can be modified via a form to include extra bits in the GROUP BY clause like:

```
HAVING (sum(op.products_quantity * op.final_price) >= 1000
AND/OR count(DISTINCT o.orders_id) > 2)
```

which doesn't exactly speed things up. there's about 5000 customers and 3000 orders at present. I added a time constraint WHERE order not older than one year but things didnt speed up after that.

i compared my local server and the online one.

- localhost linux kernel is 3.2, online 2.6,
- localhost php 5.4.4, online 5.3.26,
- localhost mysql 5.5, online 5.1,
- localhost php memory limit 128M, online 126M.

is there an obvious bottleneck? i sent an email to my webhost but didnt get a response. if I need to swap hosts I will but would like to know what to look out for. cheers,

Edit
using explain: (not sure how to format this, and no idea what it means) returns

```
`+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys               | key          | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL    | PRIMARY                     | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                |  5541 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cp    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY      | 4       | rpc.c.customers_id  |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dctc  | eq_ref | customers_id,customers_id_2 | customers_id | 4       | rpc.c.customers_id  |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dcto  | ref    | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY      | 34      | rpc.dctc.coupons_id |     0 | Using index                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dc    | ALL    | PRIMARY                     | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                |     1 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cg    | ALL    | PRIMARY                     | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                |     5 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | ALL    | PRIMARY                     | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                |  5010 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | op    | ALL    | NULL                        | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                | 10675 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+`
```

Comment: The mysql version difference is a big red flag for me.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Have you done an [explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)?

Comment: It would be useful to have the table definitions to see if all needed indexes are there :)

Comment: #winces# This doesn't solve your problem, but you're aware that columns not included in either the `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function (eg `MAX(...)`) return an uncontrollable result, right?  You won't get so much as a warning if the optimizer decides to give you different results (though since this is usually due to re-plans, logs might give you clues); this is why most RDBMSs throw _syntax errors_ for this type of query.  Also, a person's name is in no way a unique identifier - is that the `GROUP BY` criteria you really want?  And leaving first name off the `SELECT` is going to look funny

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I amended the query (and question) to reflect the modified GROUP BY clause. I also made it clearer that the additional filter is applied to the GROUP BY and not in the WHERE as incorrectly stated before. How do I paste the table definitions here? the last EXPLAIN screen dump looked horrible until some kind user edited it to look like a readable table.